# subset a dataset into multiple datsets in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset with like:

```
x

a b c d e
1 2 1 2 1
2 3 1 2 1 
3 4 5 1 3
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
1000 2 43 1 3 

y
c(2,18,20)

z
c(12,28,30)
```

i need to subset dataset x in 3 dataset where first dataset will contain col a values from y[1]:z[1] and so on

Comment: Did my answer address your needs? If so, please "accept" the answer; if not, comment and I can update it.

Comment: in my question ranges are overlapping 
so i need to have that overlapped considered

Comment: The code works fine with overlaps. Please explain what you mean by *"have that overlapped considered"*.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:30, b = 31:60)
y <- c(2, 18, 24)
z <- c(4, 21, 25)

mapply(function(a,b) dat[a:b,], y, z,
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
# [[1]]
#   a  b
# 2 2 32
# 3 3 33
# 4 4 34
# [[2]]
#     a  b
# 18 18 48
# 19 19 49
# 20 20 50
# 21 21 51
# [[3]]
#     a  b
# 24 24 54
# 25 25 55
```